# Caffe model to keras definition

Tags: tensorflow, keras, caffe

Can Any body help me how to convert this model to be used in keras. I have converted the caffe weights to h5 keras weights. But I am unable to create a keras model from this prototxt file.

The protxt file looks like this:

```
name: "VGG_CNN_M_2048"
input: "data"
input_dim: 10
input_dim: 3
input_dim: 224
input_dim: 224
layers {
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  name: "conv1"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 7
    stride: 2
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
  name: "relu1"
  type: RELU
}
layers {
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "norm1"
  name: "norm1"
  type: LRN
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0005
    beta: 0.75
    k: 2
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "norm1"
  top: "pool1"
  name: "pool1"
  type: POOLING
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  name: "conv2"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 2
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
  name: "relu2"
  type: RELU
}
layers {
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "norm2"
  name: "norm2"
  type: LRN
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0005
    beta: 0.75
    k: 2
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "norm2"
  top: "pool2"
  name: "pool2"
  type: POOLING
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv3"
  name: "conv3"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
  name: "relu3"
  type: RELU
}
layers {
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv4"
  name: "conv4"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv4"
  name: "relu4"
  type: RELU
}
layers {
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv5"
  name: "conv5"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "conv5"
  name: "relu5"
  type: RELU
}
layers {
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "pool5"
  name: "pool5"
  type: POOLING
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "fc6"
  name: "fc6"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  name: "relu6"
  type: RELU
}
layers {
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  name: "drop6"
  type: DROPOUT
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc7"
  name: "fc7"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 2048
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
  name: "relu7"
  type: RELU
}
layers {
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
  name: "drop7"
  type: DROPOUT
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc8"
  name: "fc8"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1000
  }
}
layers {
  bottom: "fc8"
  top: "prob"
  name: "prob"
  type: SOFTMAX
}
```

I know about Conv2D and Relu and Max Pooling but not sure whether it is going to work or not

Comment: what are you using for the conversion?
I remember it was possible to convert the weights (.caffemodel) not the model (.prototxt).

Comment: I converted a vgg16 with this fork on github. https://github.com/hasnainv/keras